# Convert Perl For Loop to Python

Tags: python, perl, loops, for-loop

This is what I'm attempting to convert to python

This is where I get a bit lost

```
    foreach (@files) {
        if ($_ =~ /_histogram/) { next; }   #Exclude all the histogram files

        for($row = 0, $mytype = 500; $row < $filearray_count; $row++) {
                if ($_ eq $filearray[$row][0]) { 
                $mytype = $filearray[$row][1]; 
                print "$row, $mytype,  $_ \n";
                break;
        }}


        $myfile = $mydir.$_; 

        if ($mytype > 0) {
            open($in,  "<",  ($myfile)) or die "Can't open source file $myfile: $!";

            if ($mytype >= 500) { $mytype += ++$new_attribute; }
            #print "$row, $mytype,  $_ \n";
                    this while loop is confusing. Is it setting $Instring equal to $in?
            while ($inString = <$in>) {
                $inString =~ s/^\s*(.*)\s*$/$1/;
                if ($inString =~ /Feature File Version:/) { next; }
                if ($mytype eq 11 && $inString !~ /Subject:/) { next; }

                if ($mytype eq 11 && $inString =~ /Subject:/) { 

                    my($f1, $f2, $f3) = $inString =~ m/(.*\t)(.*\t)(.*)/;
                    #print $out $inString, "\n";
                    $f3 =~ s/(\\\d{3})/\^/g;
                    print $out $mytype, "\t", $f1, $f2, $f3, "\n";

                    foreach ($f3) {
                        push @f4, split(/(Subject:|In-Reply-To:|Reply-To:|To:|From:|Bcc:|Cc:|Host:|Date:|Distribution:)/i);
                    }

                    #print $out $mytype, "\t", $f1, "\t", "scalar=", $#f4+1, "\n";
                    $count = 0;
                    while ($count < $#f4) {

                        $f4[$count+2] =~ s/\^/ /g;
                        push @f5, substr(join('', $f4[$count+1], $f4[$count+2]), 0, 50);;
                        $count = $count + 2;
```

This part is easy to understand         }

```
                    print $out $mytype, "\t", $f1, $_, "\t", $f3, "\n" for @f5;
                    undef @f4;
                    undef @f5;

                    next; 
                }
```

Not sure about the substitution here.
                    $inString =~ s/(\\d{3})/\^/g;
                    print $out $mytype, "\t", $inString, "\n";

```
            }

        }

    };
```

Comment: ... And? Where is the problem?

Comment: Unless you actually want numbers, looping over a range in Python is the wrong thing to do. Loop over the items themselves, not the indices!

Comment: From what I see in your algorithm, you don't even need the `mytype` variable

Comment: @h3nr1x asker may need it later on in the program.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like it can be done like this :

```
my_type = 500
for row, value in filearray:
   if row == member:
      my_type = value
      print row, my_type
      break
```

Comment: @user1124541 : your edit changed almost all the original question, you should revert it and ask another question for the part you don't understand...

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what do you want for `mtype`, since it's initial value of `500` is overwritten (unless you are using it further in the loop). I will just assume you need to retain the `500` value of `mtype` in each `member` in the collection `files`.

But to make your code more correct:

```
for member in files:
        mytype = 500
        x = 0 #if you really need x variable here
        for file in filearray:
            x += 1
            if member in file[0]:
                mytype = file[1]
                print(x, mytype, member)
                break
```

Comment: You could change the inner loop to `for x, file in enumerate(filearray, 1):` so you don't need to keep track of `x` manually.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what my [Pythonizer](https://github.com/snoopyjc/pythonizer/) generates for this code (after changing the "break" to a "last"):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# Generated by "pythonizer -m -v2 stack_11138297.pl" v0.967 run by JO2742 on Thu Mar 31 18:54:52 2022
import perllib, re, builtins

_str = lambda s: "" if s is None else str(s)
from perllib import Die

perllib.init_package("main")

f2 = None
count = 0
new_attribute = 0
inString = None
filearray_count = 0
f5 = perllib.Array()
files = perllib.Array()
filearray = perllib.Array()
f3 = None
out = ""
f1 = None
in_ = None
mydir = ""
x = ""
f4 = perllib.Array()

builtins.__PACKAGE__ = "main"
for _d in files:
    if re.search(r"_histogram", _str(_d)):
        continue
    # Exclude all the histogram files

    for row in range(0, (mytype := 500), filearray_count):
        if _str(_d) == _str(filearray[row][0]):

            mytype = filearray[row][1]
            perllib.perl_print(f"{row}, {mytype},  {_d} ")
            break

    myfile = mydir + _str(_d)

    if perllib.num(mytype) > 0:
        if not ((in_ := perllib.open_((myfile), "r"))):
            raise Die(f"Can't open source file {myfile}: {perllib.OS_ERROR}")

        if perllib.num(mytype) >= 500:
            mytype = perllib.num(mytype) + (new_attribute := new_attribute + 1)
        # print "$row, $mytype,  $_ \n";
        # this while loop is confusing. Is it setting $Instring equal to $in?

        while inString := perllib.readline(in_):
            inString = re.sub(r"^\s*(.*)\s*$", r"\g<1>", _str(inString), count=1)
            if re.search(r"Feature File Version:", _str(inString)):
                continue

            if _str(mytype) == _str(11) and not (
                re.search(r"Subject:", _str(inString))
            ):
                continue

            if _str(mytype) == _str(11) and (re.search(r"Subject:", _str(inString))):

                [f1, f2, f3] = perllib.list_of_n(
                    (
                        _m := re.search(r"(.*\t)(.*\t)(.*)", _str(inString)),
                        _m.groups() if _m else [],
                    )[1],
                    3,
                )
                # print $out $inString, "\n";
                f3 = re.sub(re.compile(r"(\\\d{3})"), r"^", _str(f3), count=0)
                perllib.perl_print(mytype, "\t", f1, f2, f3, "", file=out)

                for _d in f3:
                    f4.extend(
                        perllib.make_list(
                            perllib.split(
                                r"(Subject:|In-Reply-To:|Reply-To:|To:|From:|Bcc:|Cc:|Host:|Date:|Distribution:)",
                                _d,
                                flags=re.I,
                            )
                        )
                    )

                # print $out $mytype, "\t", $f1, "\t", "scalar=", $#f4+1, "\n";

                count = 0
                while count < (len(f4) - 1):

                    perllib.substitute_element(
                        f4, count + 2, re.compile(r"\^"), r" ", count=0
                    )
                    f5.extend(
                        perllib.make_list(
                            "".join(map(_str, (f4[count + 1], f4[count + 2])))[0:50]
                        )
                    )
                    count = count + 2
                    for _d in f5:
                        perllib.perl_print(mytype, "\t", f1, _d, "\t", f3, "", file=out)

                    f4 = perllib.Array()
                    f5 = perllib.Array()

                    continue

                inString = re.sub(
                    re.compile(r"(\\d{3})"), r"^", _str(inString), count=0
                )
                perllib.perl_print(mytype, "\t", inString, "", file=out)
```

Comment: Here is the perllib documentation: https://perllib.readthedocs.io/en/latest/perllib.html